# SSH command with file redirect not working

Tags: shell, ssh, quoting

I want the following command's result to redirect into a file on the remote server, as I want only unique lines in my `authorized_keys` file:

```
ssh root@10.100.10.26 awk '!seen[$0]++' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I've tried the following without success:

```
ssh root@10.100.10.26 "awk '!seen[$0]++' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys > /root/.ssh/authorized_keystemp"

ssh root@10.100.10.26 "awk \'!seen[$0]++\' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys > /root/.ssh/authorized_keystemp"

ssh root@10.100.10.26 '(awk \'!seen[$0]++\' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys > /root/.ssh/authorized_keystemp)'
```

My googles have failed me... any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think there is a straight-forward method to do that. Is `10.100.10.26` the remote server?

Comment: Quoting it should work, but you need to quote it correctly...

Comment: Whenever I run into doubly-nested quoting, I consider it time to shift the command into a script on the remote server and use ssh to run the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (I tested on my machine and it appears to work---well, I didn't have any duplicates to remove, but...):

```
ssh root@10.100.10.26 "awk '!seen[\$0]++' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys > /root/.ssh/authorized_keystemp"
```

Your `"`-quote attempts didn't work since you didn't backslash the `$` in `$0`, leading it to be expanded to something like `bash`.

Your single-quote attempt didn't work because `'foo\'some thing\'foo'` doesn't mean what you think it does. `\`-escapes are not interpreted inside single-quoted strings. So that's actually unbalanced quotes and two arguments; the first one is `foo\some` and the second is `thing'foo` but it isn't complete because that last `'` starts a new single-quoted string.

Shell escaping can be a pain, especially with double-escaping. Sending over a shell script (with `sftp`, `scp`, etc.) first and then running that is often easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to accept derobert's answer because it gave me information I needed. I still had issues, which I think might of been my `awk` command, which I replaced with an alternative approach. The following is what I did to ensure my authorized_keys file on the remote server had only unique entries:

```
ssh root@10.100.10.26 "sort /root/.ssh/authorized_keys | uniq > /root/.ssh/temp"
ssh root@10.100.10.26 "mv -f /root/.ssh/temp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Comment: I might also suggest `sort -u -o /root/.ssh/authorized_keys /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, but check that the system's sort supports the `-u` flag (it's popular but not required by POSIX).

Answer (score 0):

Here's everything you need to know about quoting something to protect it from shell expansion and word-splitting:

1. Enclose everything other than apostrophes between apostrophes. For example, `do not` becomes `'do not'`.
2. Use backslashes to escape apostrophes, i.e. `'` becomes `\'`.
3. Break your string up into apostrophes and other characters, apply the preceding 2 rules, then concatenate the results. For example, `don't` becomes `'don'\''t'`.

With these general rules, the command in your question can be properly quoted as follows:

```
ssh root@10.100.10.26 'awk '\''!seen[$0]++'\'' /root/.ssh/authorized_keys > /root/.ssh/authorized_keystemp'
```

There are more readable ways to quote the same string, but this approach is generally applicable and easy to visually verify as correct.

I find myself doing this often enough that I wrote a shell function/script to do it for me, and I use it all the time. Here it is:

```
#!/bin/sh -

# shellquote foo => foo
# shellquote foo&bar => 'foo&bar'
# shellquote foo'bar => 'foo'\''bar'
shellquote() {
  local input="$1"
  local output=""
  local backslash='\'
  local apostrophe="'"
  if [ -z "${input}" ]; then
    # Empty string => pair of apostrophes
    output="''"
  fi
  while [ -n "${input}" ]; do
    case "${input}" in
    "'"*)
      # Escape the apostrophe.
      output="${output}${backslash}${apostrophe}"
      input="${input#${apostrophe}}"
      ;;
    *"'"*)
      # Quote everything before the first apostrophe, and then escape
      # the apostrophe.
      output="${output}${apostrophe}${input%%${apostrophe}*}${apostrophe}${backslash}${apostrophe}"
      input="${input#*${apostrophe}}"
      ;;
    *[!+,./0-9:=@A-Z_a-z-]*)
      # There are no apostrophes, but at least one character needs quoting.
      # So quote the entire word.
      output="${output}${apostrophe}${input}${apostrophe}"
      input=""
      ;;
    *)
      # Nothing needs quoting. Output everything literally.
      output="${output}${input}"
      input=""
    esac
  done
  printf '%s' "${output}"
}

main() {
  local sep=''
  for arg; do
    printf '%s' "${sep}"
    shellquote "${arg}"
    sep=' '
  done
}

main "$@"
```